80 's TV series, girl with premonitions assists police with a serial killer
I can't remember the name of a series I was watching on SKY channel around the end of 80's (probably 1986-1989). It was an American TV series. The story was about this (pretty dark haired) girl who had premonitions about this serial killer. She could feel what he was feeling, and she was helping the police prevent the murders (of women, I think). When she would touch objects the serial killer touched or something, she had flashes of crime scenes, and all the feelings around it. I think after each crime, he would leave a rose at the scene, or something like that. At the end, it turned out it was her the killer was after.  

This sounds like Profiler (1990 - 2000) with Ally Walker (initially)
Wikipedia

Dr. Samantha "Sam" Waters (Ally Walker) is a forensic psychologist working for the FBI's Violent Crimes Task Force based in Atlanta, Georgia. She is a "profiler"; she has a unique gift to "see" through the eyes of others which gives Sam a special insight into the workings of the criminal mind. While she performs all of her duties diligently, her real motive lies in a both professional and personal tragedy years earlier in which her husband was murdered by a serial killer known only as Jack of All Trades.

As I recall, "Jack" had an obsession with "Sam" which led him to leave roses at crime scenes as they were Sam's favourite flower.



